# Rendering slow at 100%?

Tags: rendering

Rendering has never been a problem for me, but lately  every render of a frame, or for animation takes longer than usual.

My actual project is rendering 46 seconds per frame but once it reaches 100% it get's stuck for one minute or more leaving the final render to be 2 minutes long, it is now happening with every single .blend I have, it even get's stuck with the default scene with only one cube and no compositing.

I'm not really sure what can be causing this, but I'm open to all solutions

Comment: Did you recently change the startup file to have denoising? That would cause every file to lag behind when it renders any new project.

Comment: I did use denoising in the startup file, is denoising causing for my renders to get stuck?

Comment: It should not, at least for long, unless you changed some denoising settings that would do that.